# Поддерживает ли C++ CLI асинхронный TAP паттерн?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

Поддерживает ли C++ CLI асинхронный TAP паттерн? 
Т.е. чтобы можно было с cli библиотеки вызывать методы через async\await в управляемом коде? Если да - то где можно об этом почитать или посмотреть примеры?

p.s. под UWP не интересует.

Comment: В C++/CLI можно использовать TPL и, соответственно, TAP. Вот только ключевые слова async/await отсутствуют. Поэтому невозможно записывать асинхронный код также лаконично, как в C#/VB.Net. Придётся вручную писать тонны кода, например, с `ContinueWith`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а если взять более старые паттерны, например EAP, и обернуть их уже в TAP в самом C#? Так получится?

Comment: Обернуть в C#, а потом эту обёртку вызывать в C++/CLI? Думаю, да, получится.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, нет, именно сделать EAP реализацию асинхронки (например работы с сокетами) - в C++ CLI, и выставить ее наружу, чтобы в C# обернуть ее в TAP и работать уже с TAP?

Comment: Ну, я не вижу никаких препятствий. Вот только почему бы весь код не написать на C#?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да собственно есть нативная уже готовая библиотека, оборачивать которую в p\invoke нужно много времени (очень много структур описывать). Поэтому решил сделать вместо p\invoke - CLI реализацию, меньше кода.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, добавьте ответ, чтобы вопрос не висел открытым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы метод можно было вызывать через async/await в C#, он должен возвращать `System::Threading::Tasks::Task^` или `System::Threading::Tasks::Task<T>^`.

Соответственно проблем с определением такого метода в C++/CLI нет. Проблема, однако, в использовании его из C++/CLI, т. к. C++/CLI не поддерживает `async`-функции. Проблемы с использованием из C# быть не должно.

---

На самом деле, необязательно возвращать `System::Threading::Tasks::Task^`, достаточно возвратить *tasklike*. *Tasklike* определяется как такой тип, который обладает доступным методом (возможно, методом расширения) `GetAwaiter()`, причём возвращаемый тип `GetAwaiter()` должен

- реализовать интерфейс `System::Runtime::CompilerServices::INotifyCompletion`,
- иметь доступное для чтения нестатическое свойство `IsCompleted` типа `bool`, и
- иметь доступный необобщённый нестатический метод `GetResult()` без параметров

В частности, классы `System::Threading::Tasks::Task^` и `System::Threading::Tasks::Task<T>^` удовлетворяют этим условиям.

Документация: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#await-expressions

Comment: Отличные новости, спасибо.

Comment: Вы наверное опечатались, "System::Threading::Tasks::Task^ или System::Threading::Tasks::Task^"

Comment: @User983475: Точно! Исправил. Заодно дополнил ответ.